# Is this temporary std::string expression acceptable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, stdstring, temporary-objects

I realize this isn't the most efficient thing to do, but is it acceptable C++ by most to create temporary `std::string` objects for concatenation, like here in line 4?

```
constexpr const char* const a = "This is ";
constexpr const char* const b = "a test.";

std::string s2 = std::string(a) + std::string(b);
std::cout << "*** " << s2 << std::endl;
```

I have to update some code in many, many places that previously used `std::string` concatenation to now use these `constexpr` character string constants, and it seems easier to just drop in some `std::string(...)` constructors to update the code rapidly.

This works in Visual C++ as I have it listed, and seems to compile in a gcc version that supports C++14 (need to test it yet).

Comment: It wouldn't really bother me, if I were to review this code; especially if it's not on performance-sensitive path. You could save one heap allocation, and some typing, with `std::string(a) + b` (except that in your example the strings are so short that a small-string optimization likely kicks in).

Comment: Is it *acceptable*? Sure, why not? Is it *efficient*? Not necessarily. But in this particular example, it would be far better to use `std::cout << "*** " << a << b << std::endl;` instead. If you really wanted to avoid concatenating `std::string`s, you could use a `std::ostringstream`, eg: `std::string s2 = (std::ostringstream() << a << b).str(); std::cout << "*** " << s2 << std::endl;` Or (gasp) a `char[]`, eg (which a `std::string` would do internally anyway): `char s2[32]; size_t offset = strcpy(s2, a); strcpy(s2+offset, b); std::cout << "*** " << s2<< std::endl;`

Comment: String UDLs may occasionally be adaquate: `"This is "s` and `"a test."s`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid but inefficient and slightly unattractive solution. Note that it is sufficient to cast the first operand into a `std::string`. This is slightly more efficient.

**Starting with C++20** [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) is the best way to do this.

**If you are stuck on an older standard**, you can replace it by [`fmt::format()`](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html) from the [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

int main() {
    constexpr const char* const a = "This is ";
    constexpr const char* const b = "a test.";

    std::string str = std::format("{}{}", a, b);
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

**Starting with C++17** [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view) should be used instead of c-string-literals.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view a = "This is ";
    constexpr std::string_view b = "a test.";

    std::string str = std::format("{}{}", a, b);
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

**Starting with C++23** you should use [`std::print()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print) (or [`std::println()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/println)) instead of `std::cout`. It makes sure your output is printed in the correct encoding. Especially in the Windows CMD `std::cout` causes problems as soon as you deviate from ASCII. `std::print` always works correctly.

```cpp
#include <print>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view a = "This is ";
    constexpr std::string_view b = "a test.";

    std::println("{}{}", a, b);
}
```